# Performance Test in same condition

Tags: c, linux, performance, macos, performance-testing

I have program in C and I want to test performance of my code! But I want change and test again and again! I want to run all of test in exactly same condition(same memory available, in general same resource available). 
I am developing on MacOS 10.9 but I need tool works on both mac an linux!
Could you suggest any?
Thanks!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I support your efforts in doing what you just stated.

Comment: I need tool for do this test in same condition! Do you have any suggestion? (A tool that promise same condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the  [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command:

```
 time yourprogram yourarguments....
```

and you could limit resources with e.g. [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), concretely using the [ulimit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ulimit.1.html) shell builtin. See [this](https://superuser.com/a/220064/107016).

Notice that the [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29) is providing resources (and can be seen as a resource itself, or at least as a resource manager). So with different OSes you cannot have *exactly* the *same* resources (and conditions)! For instance, [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and [scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) are different on Linux and on MacOSX, and they are an important resource provided and managed by the OS kernel.

Comment: but how can ensure same condition?

Comment: If You Switch betreten Mac/Linux basically no one can wrt software but only for hardware.

Comment: Use  `ulimit` to set limits. But I don't understand what you mean by same condition: the kernel would be by hypothesis be different!

Comment: Same memory amount available, and any other resource

Comment: What does "same memory" mean to you? What kind of memory do you think about?? Why can't you use `ulimit -m 16384` .... ?

Comment: Thanks I got my answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. in your case if performance means execution time, then simple shell script like

date
your c file execution 
date

this will tell you the required output.

1. if you need actual performance (time,cpu,memory,etc) then on Linux sar utility can be used which will provide all the performance counters.
   after which you can analyze the data and get the performance of your code
2. use profilers for your code which will tell you performance of your code with suggestions if any are present
3. use static code analyzers (feed your code as input to code analyzer which will tell you the performance of your code and possible enhancements)